# Getting in trouble while splitting a string in PHP

Tags: php

I've the following code.

```
$var1 = 'This is line1

         This is line2

         This is line3';

$var_arr = explode("\n", $var1); // or preg_split("/\n/", $var1); same
echo '<ul type = "disc" class="deal_data" >';
foreach($var_arr as $var1)
{                             
   echo '<li><p>'.$var1.'</p></li>';                                 
} 
echo '</ul>';
echo 'String Length:'.strlen($var_arr[1]);
```

Its output is:

[image: Output]

How do the second and fourth list items get a length different from zero?

Comment: \n means "new line" -- how many lines do you count?

Answer (score 1):

I can see that there are two new lines in your `$var1`,

try this

```
explode("\n\n", $var1);
```

**[phpFiddle Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dni-w50)**

Comment: I tested the code on http://phpfiddle.com and found correct. go there and try the above code

Answer (score 1):

Add an explode delimeter,`\r`:

```
<?php
    $var1 = 'This is line1

             This is line2

             This is line3';

    $var_arr = explode("\n\r", $var1); // or preg_split("/\n/", $var1); same
    echo '<ul type = "disc" class="deal_data" >';
    foreach($var_arr as $var1)
    {
        echo '<li><p>'.$var1.'</p></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo 'String Length:'.strlen($var_arr[1]);
?>
```

The result is:

```
<ul type = "disc" class="deal_data" >
    <li>
        <p>This is line1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>This is line2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>This is line3</p>
    </li>
</ul>
String Length:24
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your input has five lines, two of which are empty:

```php
$var1 = 'This is line1 /* Line 1 */
                       /* Line 2 */
         This is line2 /* Line 3 */
                       /* Line 4 */
         This is line3 /* Line 5 */';
```

Comment: this is not a real answer.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ the question was "How [are the] 2nd and 4th list items getting some length?". I'm pretty sure this is a real answer to that question...

Comment: It is obvious that the guy is asking how to remove the blank list items. Even the question is how it is showing?

Answer (score 0):

Your text lines are separated by two newlines. You're exploding on one newline so you get array entries for the blank lines as well as the ones with text in.

Try

```
 $var_arr = explode("\n\n", $var1);
```

Comment: results only single element array.

Comment: Maybe. If the EOL is actually "\n\r" as might happen in Windows, that would be the case. It's not actually possible to tell from the original posting.

Answer (score 0):

A condition into for command may help you...

```
$var1 = 'This is line1

         This is line2

         This is line3';

$var_arr = explode("\n", $var1); // or preg_split("/\n/", $var1); same
echo '<ul type = "disc" class="deal_data" >';
foreach($var_arr as $var1)
{                             
   if($var1!="")
       echo '<li><p>'.$var1.'</p></li>';                                 
} 
echo '</ul>';
echo 'String Length:'.strlen($var_arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter and trim your array :

```
$var1 = 'This is line1

         This is line2

         This is line3';

$var_arr = explode("\n", $var1);
$var_arr = array_filter(array_map("trim",$var_arr));

var_dump(array_values($var_arr));
```

Output

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'This is line1' (length=13)
  1 => string 'This is line2' (length=13)
  2 => string 'This is line3' (length=13)
```